# Java script: Updating multiple json array variables in descriptive notation in one go

Tags: javascript

Considering the below json

```
var jsonObj  = {
    schema {
        "attribs": {
          "size": "5",
          "sort": [
            {
              "timestamp": {
                "order": "desc",
                "unmapped_type": "boolean"
              }
            },          
            {
                timestamp: {
                 "order": "desc",
                 "unmapped_type": "boolean"
            }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

In order to edit size i just have to write:

```
 jsonObj["schema"]["attribs"]["size"] = "5"
```

and it works.

But how do i edit the sort details if i need the order to be ascending ("asc") in place descending ("desc"). And how to update multiple sort options in one go.

Comment: same as you did for size?
`jsonObj["schema"]["attribs"]["sort"][0]["timestamp"]["order"] = "asc"`

Comment: `jsonObj["schema"]["attribs"]["sort"][0]["timestamp"]["order"] = "asc"`

Comment: thanks - I was actually trying to use .get (as per some online link). Never realized it would be so simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to write it like that in JavaScript. Just write

```
var jsonObj = {
  schema: {
    attribs: {
      size: "5",
      sort: [
        {
          timestamp: {
            order: "desc",
            unmapped_type: "boolean"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

And you definitely don't have to use index syntax to access it. Remember JSON is derived from JavaScript Object literals. (JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation)

```
jsonObj.schema.attribs.size = "5";
```

So to update the sort order of timestamp just write

```
jsonObj.schema.attribs.sort[0].timestamp.order = "asc";
```

to set the sort order of all sort fields to `"asc"` you can write

```
jsonObj.schema.attribs.sort.forEach(attrib => {
  Object.keys(attrib).forEach(key => attrib[key].order = "desc");
});
```

Here is an example:

```js
var jsonObj = {
  schema: {
    attribs: {
      size: "5",
      sort: [
        {
          timestamp: {
            order: "desc",
            unmapped_type: "boolean"
          }
        },
        {
          name: {
            order: "desc",
            unmapped_type: "string"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};

jsonObj.schema.attribs.sort.forEach(console.log);

jsonObj.schema.attribs.sort.forEach(attrib => {
  Object.keys(attrib).forEach(key => attrib[key].order = "asc");
});

jsonObj.schema.attribs.sort.forEach(console.log);
```

Comment: Huddad: What is the difference between this and jsonObj["schema"]["attribs"]["sort"][0]["timestamp"]["order"] = "asc" . This one seems less complex.

Comment: `.` syntax is easier to read. You only really want just that field?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Honestly, for this one of case i felt jsonObj["schema"]["attribs"]["sort"][0]["timestamp"]["order"] = "asc" is more easy to read because of the simpl json here, but maybe when it gets complicated, will go the way you suggested.

Comment: I updated example with simple use case and `.` notation. And I made a generic example that is distinct.

Comment: Thanks @Aluan Haddad - this is really helpful and gives clarity.

Comment: jsonObj.schema.attribs.sort.forEach(attrib => {
  Object.keys(attrib).map(key => attrib[key]).order = "asc";
});


console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));

//no change noticed
{"schema":{"attribs":{"size":"5","sort":[{"timestamp":{"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}},
                                         {"timestamp":{"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}}]}}}

Comment: @StillNestling thank you, silly mistake I made (note to self: test more) it is now fixed.

Comment: updated question as per your solution for a more general problem - solution

Comment: @StillNestling Thank you :D I also added inline runnable stack snippet.

Answer (score 1):

This is an array notation of JSON - you may use the below syntax to update:

```
 jsonObj["schema"]["attribs"]["sort"][0]["timestamp"]["order"] = "asc"
```

The index starts from 0

Comment: What do you mean? Only `sort` is an array.